# Infragistics XamDataGrid LoadCustomizations issue

Tags: performance, infragistics, xamdatagrid

I discovered very interested issue with XamDataGrid LoadCustomizations method.
At start program I initialize XamDataGrid object, bind it to datasource, call LoadCustomizations(), put it into new TabItem control and add TabItem to TabControl.

The problem is very slow perfomance after that. If I will call LoadCustomizations method later (by user click at some button) XamDataGrid perfomance is good. How can I resolve this problem and why LoadCustomizations at first case makes it work bad?

I try to find some binding warnings/errors, but here is no errors/warning.

Thanks for answers and sorry for my bad english.

Comment: it appears that you have resolved your performance issue based on this post on the Infragistics forums: http://blogs.infragistics.com/forums/p/67264/341693.aspx#341693  Can you confirm that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found issue in another piece of my code where I try get LabelPresenter of my grid (but when datasource is empty xamdatagrid doesn't show any column label). I add IF condition where I check datasource count property. It works good.